# Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue Using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hangfire

I've just started to try and use Hangfire. I've installed successfully but I'm having difficulty creating the first job.

```
Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(Function() Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget"))
```

This won't compile:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Enqueue' can be
>   called with these arguments:
>       'Public Shared Overloads Function Enqueue(Of T)(methodCall As Expression(Of Action(Of T))) As String': Type parameter 'T' cannot be
>   inferred.
>       'Public Shared Overloads Function Enqueue(Of T)(methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Task))) As String': Type parameter 'T' cannot
>   be inferred.

Any ideas how to fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Console.WriteLine` method doesn't return anything. Just replace `Function` keyword with `Sub` to get a working expression tree:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget"))
```